# What does the inverse of Euler's phi function mean?

Tags: analytic-number-theory

Since $\varphi$ (Euler's totient function) is the Dirichlet product of $\mu$ and $N$, we can use properties of inverses to show that

$$\varphi^{-1} (n) = \sum_{d|n} d \mu(d).$$

Furthermore, for multiplicative functions $f$, we can find that

$$\sum_{d|n} \mu(d) f(d) = \prod_{p|n} (1 - f(p)).$$

As a result, we can find that

$$\varphi^{-1} (n) = \prod_{p|n} (1 - p).$$

I understand how this formula for $\varphi^{-1}$ was derived, but I have no idea what it actually means.

When $\varphi(6) = 6 \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{2}{3} = 2$, but why isn't $\varphi^{-1} (2) = 6$? Instead, $\varphi^{-1} (2) = (1 - 2) = -1$. I also understand that the $\varphi$ function is not injective, so how do I relate $-1$ to all $n$ such that $\varphi(n) = 2$?

Comment: Where did you find this calculation?

Comment: [Mobius inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula) doesn't find an inverse function in the sense you are thinking of.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Introduction to Analytic Number Theory by Apostol, section 2.11

Comment: @lulu: Ok that makes sense, but then what exactly is the significance of the Dirichlet inverse of $\varphi$, and does it relate to the inverse in the sense that I am thinking of?

Comment: No, it doesn't.  It happens, in studying arithmetic functions, that one comes across functions  that satisfy $F(n)=\sum_{d\,|\,n}f\left( \frac nd\right)$ for some other arithmetic function $f$.  For example  $n=\sum_{d\,|\,n}\varphi \left(\frac nd\right)$.  We then want to know if we can write $f(n)$ in some sensible way in terms of $F$.  Mobius inversion gives us a way to do that.

Comment: @lulu: Oh, interesting! Thank you.

Comment: I think it would help if you work out (or maybe read up on) what the unit is for the Dirichlet product.